# Where does Page number and Cont. come from

Tags: page-numbering

Please bear with me. I am a newbie to TEX.
The following code creates page number at the top and Cont. at the bottom right of each page as you can see in the image.

But I am not sure where these come from. Please let me know which codes are responsible for these. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.3in, right=0.3in, top=0.7in, bottom=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathexam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\imagescale}{0.7}

\ExamClass{Grade 8 Math}
\ExamName{Geometry of Polygon, Length and Area}


\let\ds\displaystyle

\begin{document}
\parbox[b][3cm][c]{12cm}{

\textbf{First Name (Print):} \hrulefill \\
\\
\textbf{Last Name (Print):}  \hrulefill }

\begin{enumerate}
Content here.
More content.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Page 3 of 7 at the top-right.
[image]

Cont. at the bottom-right.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those headers and footers are set up by the `mathexam` package. If you want to remove the header and footer, add `nohdr` as an option to the package, i.e. write

```
\usepackage[nohdr]{mathexam}
```

instead of

```
\usepackage{mathexam}
```

If you just want to remove the page numbers and the footer, you can use the features from `fancyhdr`, which is the package used by `mathexam` to set them up. Adding

```
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
```

to the preamble somewhere after `\usepackage{mathexam}` will remove the footer and the right part of the header (the page numbers).